# how do i Add current root drive to raid array?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I had Ubuntu on my first HDD, i attached another HDD to PC, now i want to configure software raid 0 with existing Ubuntu installation. with those two HDD

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a single drive into RAID you need to:

1. partition new disk and create single-drive software RAID (with only new drive attached)
2. copy the data, for example using rsync or dd into new raid partition
3. install grub on second drive and reconfigure grub to boot from raid device
4. then, once it's booted from RAID, attach the old drive to the RAID

There are tutorials available that describes step-by-step process with command examples.

One of them is: https://sysadmin.compxtreme.ro/how-to-migrate-a-single-disk-linux-system-to-software-raid1/ - but keep it mind, it's kinda outdated and refers to raid1. This is just to show you the idea about this process.

Before you do anything: remember to do your backup!